# Explain syntax of <?=@

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm following a PHP/AJAX tutorial on form validation. (I'm new to php!).

Could someone explain the syntax of this line:

```
<?=@$_REQUEST['username']?>
```

The context is the `value` attribute of an `input` field.

I know how `$_REQUEST` works. I just don't get the `<?=@` part. I understand `<?` can be used in lieu of `<?php` (but isn't always supported!) and `<?=$variable?>` is special syntax for echoing variables. What does the `@` symbol do?

Thanks.

Links:

[Form validation tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/using-ajax-to-validate-forms)

[Explanation for special syntax](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?52085-lt-instead-of-lt-php)

Comment: `<?` is a PHP shorttag, adding the equalsign `<?=` is a sort of shortcut for echo, so the result is outputted.

Comment: And BTW, that's horrible code. Never write something like this.

Comment: Not my baby. I completely agree!

Comment: I concur, this information can be found in:

[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Though Amal's answer is more concise, detailed and does not require venturing elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<?= ?>` is the [short echo syntax](http://php.net/echo). `<?=$var?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $var; ?>`.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/echo):

> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

`@` is the [error suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

In short, `<?=@$_REQUEST['username']?>` will try to print out the value of `$_REQUEST['username']` (without ouputting any errors). It's not a good practice and shouldn't be used in your code. If you don't want to display the errors, turn off `display_errors` in your `php.ini` configuration and log them instead.

Comment: Or better yet, check if the var is set before echoing.